# How to customize font-lock-syntactic-face-function?

Tags: font-lock

I've found I can make some comments use a different face by customizing `font-lock-syntactic-face-function`.

*To give some context, I'm setting some comments to use `font-lock-doc-face`, in situations the major mode isn't setting it.*

---

Currently I'm swapping in a new function, while it works using `setq` seems clunky.

```el
;; Just an example.
(defconst mycustom-comment-prefix "////")
(defvar mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function-original nil)
(defun mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function (state)
  (cond
    ;; Check if this comment starts with `mycustom-comment-prefix'.
    ((and (nth 4 state)
       (let ((p (nth 8 state)))
         (string-equal
           mycustom-comment-prefix
           (buffer-substring-no-properties p (+ p (length mycustom-comment-prefix)))))
       'font-lock-doc-face)
      (t
        ;; Default behavior.
        (funcall mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function-original state))))

  ;; --- snip ---

  ;; When enabling...
  (setq mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function-original
    font-lock-syntactic-face-function)

  ;; Restore when disabling...
  (setq font-lock-syntactic-face-function
    mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function-original))
```

Is there a better way to handle the function override?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about "the best way" or "is there a better way" are too broad and invite primarily opinion-based answers. As such they're off-topic here.

Comment: Seems reasonable, I wasn't sure how to phrase this question, I'm interested to customize font locking and not sure if I'm overriding this in the right way.

Comment: You may be able to find a more specific question, perhaps by looking closer at something you are doing which doesn't do what you expect, or by asking how to do some specific thing. Underneath a vague or broad request for ideas or advice there are often some specific problems or questions. I'm guessing that's the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the details of what is "this" is missing, as is the explanation of what you find clunky, but I'd recommend you use `add-function` and `remove-function` instead of `setq`:

```lisp
(defun mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function (orig-fun state)
  ;; Check if this comment starts with `mycustom-comment-prefix'.
  (if (and (nth 4 state)
           (save-excursion
             (goto-char (nth 8 state))
             (looking-at mycustom-comment-prefix)))
      'font-lock-doc-face
    ;; Default behavior.
    (funcall orig-fun state)))

  ;; --- snip ---

  ;; When enabling...
  (add-function :around (local 'font-lock-syntactic-face-function)
                #'mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function)

  ;; Restore when disabling...
  (remove-function (local 'font-lock-syntactic-face-function)
                   #'mycustom-font-lock-syntactic-face-function)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, clarified `this`